# How I can find the right path in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

sub i have a problem i need to find in the html "Derzeit nicht verfügbar."

```
<div id="availability" class="a-section a-spacing-none }">

<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price">    

Derzeit nicht verfügbar.


<div id="all-offers-display" class="a-section">
```

I tried it already with below code but doesn't work.

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price' and text()='Derzeit nicht verfügbar. ']")`

Comment: What's the error when it did not work ?

Comment: maybe first get all `text()` and see what you get. This text in HTML has also spaces, tabs, enters which you don't have in `text()='Derzeit nicht verfügbar. '`. OR you should use something like `contains(text(), 'Derzeit nicht verfügbar.')`

Comment: OR maybe you should check `'Derzeit nicht verfügbar.'` without space after dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get it if I use text without space after dot

```
text()='Derzeit nicht verfügbar.'
```

But sometimes it is simpler to check if it `contains` expected text.

```
contains(text(), 'Derzeit nicht verfügbar.')
```

---

Testing example

```
from selenium import webdriver

html = '''
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price">Derzeit nicht verfügbar.</span>
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price">Derzeit nicht verfügbar. </span>
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price"> Derzeit nicht verfügbar. </span>

<div id="availability" class="a-section a-spacing-none }">
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price">

Derzeit nicht verfügbar. 

<div id="all-offers-display" class="a-section">
Other text
'''

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

print('\n--- Example 1 - with space ---\n')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price' and text()='Derzeit nicht verfügbar. ']")
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
    print('---')

print('\n--- Example 2 - without space ---\n')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price' and text()='Derzeit nicht verfügbar.']")
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
    print('---')

print('\n--- Example 3 - contains ---\n')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price' and contains(text(), 'Derzeit nicht verfügbar.')]")
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
    print('---')
```